# How can I get the HTTP status code from ServletResponse without using a ServletFilter?

Tags: java, servlets, httpresponse

I'm setting the http status in doPost() of servlet as

```
if(success)    
{    
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);    
}else{    
  response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Message");    
}
```

In client side after calling the server as:

```
HttpResponse aHttpResponseL = client.execute(aHttpPostL);    
BufferedReader aBufferedReaderL = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                aHttpResponseL.getEntity().getContent()));
```

But always I'm getting **null** as value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relevance of ServletFilter in this question? Did you get the response code when you used ServletFilter? if so, how?

Comment: no i saw some post using servlet filter but its too long(i didnt try that also). so only

Comment: Take a look at this [SO] question.


  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782517/how-can-i-retrieve-the-msg-from-httpservletresponse-senderror

Answer (score 0):

Check the status line:

```
HttpResponse aHttpResponseL = client.execute(aHttpPostL);  
int code = aHttpResponseL.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Thanks Kothvandir, its working but how to get the Status message?

Comment: Did you try the getReasonPhrase? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getReasonPhrase()

Comment: Are you asking for the correspondence between code and "code description text" like 200 OK, 201 CREATED, etc? The HttpStatus Class stores all the http status codes but I don't think there's a class that provides the String description of this codes.

Comment: Ya thats fine, but for error    "response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Message");" is it possible to get the message?

Comment: A post about how to obtain the message: stackoverflow.com/a/2925207/1297972

Comment: Sorry kothvandir, Im new to java. I try with the link which u gave above,In getReasonPhrase still im getting http description message.     While im using the below code "BufferedReader aBufferedReaderL = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(aHttpResponseL.getEntity().getContent()));" im getting only message not code